# How can I use NoConflict With The Following Script?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

How Can I Write Jquery.No Conflict With The Following Jquery Script. I am Using this Jquery to Slide images on my page. How Can I use No conflict with the following Script ?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#waterwheel-carousel-default").waterwheelCarousel();

    $("#waterwheel-carousel-higharch").waterwheelCarousel({
        startingWaveSeparation: -90,
        waveSeparationFactor: .7,
        centerOffset: 10,
        startingItemSeparation: 120,
        itemSeparationFactor: .9,
        itemDecreaseFactor: .75
    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: NoConflict it's when you use mootols or prototype with jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's explained in the documentation:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 1):

noConflict is typically used when you  need to use another library with jquery so the two dont clash. From jQuery docs:

> Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just
>   as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so
>   all functionality is available without using $. If we need to use
>   another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, we can return control of
>   $ back to the other library with a call to $.noConflict():

So unless youre using another library with jquery i dont think you need noconflict.

Answer (score 0):

well, you should make another "shortcut" to jquery :

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

after this, replace all your `$` signs with the name of the variable that points to jquery now (`$j`).

Another approach would be to write your jquery code into a function and pass the jquery reference (`$`) as an argument :

```
(function($){
    // your jquery code goes here
    // alert($ === jQuery);
})(jQuery.noConflict());
// outside the scope, $ is not jquery anymore
// alert($ === jQuery);
```